# Span inside H2 tag not showing up

Tags: html, css, caret, html-heading

I'm trying to add a span inside of an H2 tag that will show a caret for dropdown, but everything I try I can't get it to render. When I look in the developer console my span doesn't even show up. Looks like it's not even being rendered. Is there something in the H2 style that I need to override? I can't find it.

HTML

```
<h2 class="panel-title">Drilldown<span style="float:right" class="down_caret" id="drilldown_caret"></span></h2>
```

CSS for H2

```
.dashboard-row .dashboard-panel h2.panel-title {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 55px 5px 10px;
    font-weight: 200;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
h2, h3 {
    line-height: normal;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 27px;
}
h1, h2, h3 {
    line-height: 32px;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    margin: 8px 0;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 16px;
    color: inherit;
    text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
}
user agent stylesheeth2 {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    -webkit-margin-before: 0.83em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 0.83em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

CSS for span class
.down_caret {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-top: 6px solid #000000;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 0 dotted;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  content: "";
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sandenay/57sbzfmv/1/

Comment: May be your caret is showing up? Span is visible though

Comment: Working here http://jsfiddle.net/sandenay/57sbzfmv/2/

Comment: Did you check any other css class affected to the caret?